# how use url_for with a redirected route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this in routes.rb

```
  match '/external_login' => 'admin#external_login', :as => :external_login, :via => [:get,:post]
```

And I want to generate a friendly url (for my spanish public) "proveedores"

so I have added in routes.rb:

```
get '/proveedores', to: redirect('/external_login')
```

To use a link like http.//...n/proveedores

but now I need to use url_for helper that builds http.//...n/proveedores. **But How?**

`url_for (controller: "admin", action: "external_login")` don't return "/proveedores" reuturn "/external_login" instead

And if I put in routes.rb

```
  match '/proveedores' => 'admin#external_login', :as => :external_login, :via => [:get,:post]
```

It crash when type in browser http:...localhost:3000/proveedores

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/external_login"
```

---

A solution, but I think I'm missing somethig

In routes, two lines:

```
  match '/proveedores', to: 'admin#external_login', :as => :external_login, :via => [:get,:post]
  get '/external_login', to: "admin#external_login"
```

And now I can do this:

```
2.0.0-p451 :003 > url_for(controller: "admin", action: "external_login")
 => "http://10.210.nn.nnn:3000/proveedores"
```

Can somebody explain, if this is correct, or maybe there is a simpler solution

Thanks

---

Thanks to Ashutosh Tiwari, the solution is simpler than it looks. Using the `_url` helper instead of `url_for(....`

routes.rb:

```
 match '/external_login', to: 'admin#external_login', :as => :external_login, :via => [:get,:post]
  get '/proveedores', to: redirect('/external_login')
```

and using `proveedores_url` i get the full url: `"http://10.210.nn.nnn:3000/proveedores"`

Comment: What do you mean by crashes? Can you post the error?

Comment: Yes sorry, added to the Question

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? `match` isn't allowed in Rails 4.

Comment: I'm using Rails 4, I didn't knou I can't use match, I have a lot of `match` in routes.rb ¿? and without warnings

Comment: `match` can be used in rails 4, but with a verb or verbs specified with `:via`, which you are doing. So that is all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes generates for two type of helpers for you, first one is `routes_name_path` and another is `routes_name_url`.

`_url` helper provides you the absolute path while `_path` helper provides relative path.

You can use `_url` helper method instead of `url_for` that will be something like `admin_proveedores_url`.

Comment: Yes, that is, simpliest solution, I've added to my question